# Finding Probability on a biased die

Tags: python, probability, probability-theory

I had to simulate a biased die such that 6 occurs more than 50% of the times. Which I was able to do using:

```
from random import randint,choice
def bdie():
    out = random.randint(0,2)
    if (out==1 or out == 2):
        return 6
    else:
        r = choice([i for i in range(1,7) if i not in [6]])
        return r

def bdthrow(n):
    output = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        if n>0 & n<=100000000:
            outcome = bdie()
            output.append(outcome)
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    print(output)
```

For which the output would be:

> [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 5, 4]

Now on this biased die I am supposed to find the probability of top face being 5 and I need to find the average count of each face of the die.

Now solving the sum on a paper is easy where I can find the probability but I'm not sure how to implement this in python.

Comment: Do you need the realized probability of rolling 5 ? (I.e. the count of how many times 5 is the rolled value) or the pure theoretical probability of getting a 5 given that P(6>0.5)?

Comment: I just need the pure probability not considering the number of throws.

Comment: I don't understand the question: do you want to know how to compute a sum in python ? or plot things ? or both ?

Comment: I just edited the question a little. I just need help computing the probability of getting 5 and getting the average count of each face on such a biased die. Hope this clears it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for an unbiased estimator of getting 5. Such an estimator can be the number of 5 obtains when throwing the dice enough times. I.e `# fives / n`.

From memory perspective I would recommend using `defaultdict`. Also there is no need to check the value of `n` on every round.

```
from random import randint,choice
from collections import defaultdict

def bdie():
    out = randint(0,2)
    if (out==1 or out == 2):
        return 6
    else:
        r = choice([i for i in range(1,7) if i not in [6]])
        return r

def bdthrow(n):
    output = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(0,n):
        outcome = bdie()
        output[outcome] +=1
    return (float(output[5])/n)
```

There are few other optimisations to the code but naively that should work.